# How can I get href URL with countdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I've created a button with 10 seconds timer but that is happening with onclick function. I know I shouldn't use onclick function in element. But Is there any way to get href URL It mean when I click on button It should start countdown and after countdown completion it should get URL from href and redirect. If you want to check you can visit here https://mamutemplates.blogspot.com/

```js
var l = 0; function myFunction2(url1) {var tt1 = setInterval(function() {
    l = l + 1; var counter = 10 - l;
    button2.innerHTML = 'You will be redirected After:' + counter;
    if (counter === 0) { clearInterval(tt1); window.location = url1;    }
  }, 1000);}; var i = 0;
function myFunction(url) { var tt = setInterval(function() {
    i = i + 1; var counter = 10 - i;
    button1.innerHTML = 'You will be redirected After' + counter;
    if (counter === 0) {  clearInterval(tt); window.location = url; }
  }, 1000);};
```

```css
#button2{padding: 10px;
    border:3px solid #eee;
    background: #27ae60;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:  120px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
#download2{text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;text-align: center;
  color:#ffffff;  }
 #button1{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border:3px solid #eee;
    background:#2573a6;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:  120px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }#download1{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#ffffff;

}
```

```html
<div class="pr3" id="second">
<button id="button1">
<a href="#" id="download1" onclick="myFunction('https://google.com')">Download</a>
</button>
<button id="button2">
<a href="#" id="download2" onclick="myFunction2('https://google.com.pk')">DEMO</a>
</button><br />
```

Comment: I think setTimeout would be more appropriate than setInterval

Answer (score 1):

what you need is `element.getAttribute("href")`:https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-getattribute/

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.onclick = function() {

var timer = setInterval(timerCount, 1000)
var t = 10;
function timerCount() {
                
                t--;
                if (t < 0) {
                                console.log("times up");
                                                                window.location.href = url
                                clearInterval(timer)
                } else {
                                console.log(t)
                }
                
                
}
}
```

I think you will be able to figure the rest of it if you want:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the `href` attribute on your buttons, then implementation goes as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", demoHandler);

var l = 0;

function demoHandler(event) {

  let url = event.target.getAttribute('href');
  var tt1 = setInterval(function() {
    l = l + 1;
    var counter = 10 - l;
    button2.innerHTML = 'You will be redirected After:' + counter;
    if (counter === 0) {
      clearInterval(tt1);
      window.location = url;
    }
  }, 1000);
};
var i = 0;

function myFunction(url) {
  var tt = setInterval(function() {
    i = i + 1;
    var counter = 10 - i;
    button1.innerHTML = 'You will be redirected After' + counter;
    if (counter === 0) {
      clearInterval(tt);
      window.location = url;
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
#button2 {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  background: #27ae60;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#button1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  background: #2573a6;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="pr3" id="second">
  <button id="button1">
<a href="#" id="download1" onclick="myFunction('https://google.com')">Download</a>
</button>
  <button id="button2" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com.">DEMO</a>
</button><br />
```

Comment: That's good. But I should use href attribute, So, Is is possible to get href link after 10 seconds. I mean when someone click on the button he should wait even timer will end and then button get a link from href attribute and redirect it.

Comment: Yes it's possible using the same code base you have. I have edited the code to reflect how you can use the `href` attribute instead of the `data-href` discussed earlier.